# Click to scroll inside an overflowed horizontal div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, carousel

I'm using the following code to build a image carousel in a page. I added a bit of JS code to be able to scroll to a specific image when clicking on them, but it's not working as I expect. That is, when I click on an image I want the div to scroll to that specific image.

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-frame">
    <ul>
        <li class="carousel-item">
            <img width="600" height="400" src="img01.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-item">
            <img width="600" height="400" src="img02.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-item">
            <img width="600" height="400" src="img03.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-item">
            <img width="600" height="400" src="img04.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-frame {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel-frame ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.carousel-frame li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.carousel-frame .carousel-item').on('click', function(e) {
    var slideWidth = $(this).width();
    var scrollTo = $(this).position().left;
    var offset = scrollTo - (slideWidth / 2);
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({
        scrollLeft: offset
    }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/occrnja9/9/

Comment: "it's not working as I need" is not a good description of your problem. Could you please explain and show what is not working correctly (an image can help).

Comment: Sorry. When I click on an image I need the div to scroll to that specific image. Right now, when I click on some of the images the div scrolls back to the beginning. Not sure if I explained myself.

Comment: When you click an image, you want the div to scroll to the CLICKED image? That is, you want the clicked image to be aligned in the center of the div?

Comment: Exactly, I want the clicked image to be aligned in the center of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution.

JS:

```
$('.carousel-frame .carousel-item').on('click', function(e) {
    var container = $(this).parent().parent();
    var slideWidth = $(this).width();
    var frameWidth = container.width() / 2;
    var slidePosition = $(this).position().left;
    var offset = container.scrollLeft() + slidePosition - frameWidth + slideWidth / 2;
    container.animate({
        scrollLeft: offset
    }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/occrnja9/10/